# Como desativar checkbox no tinymce baseado em valor de listbox

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Criei um *popup* no *tinymce* para WordPress, para inserção de *shortcodes* de vídeo na página. Ao abrir a janela, ela mostra um *menu listbox* com várias opções de origem do vídeo (sites como YouTube, Vimeo, etc) e um *checkbox*, se marcado, faz o vídeo ser embutido com a opção *autoplay*.

Uma versão simplificada, para melhor compreensão:

```
 ( function() {
tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'fb_test', function( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'fb_test_button_key', {
        type: 'listbox',
        text: 'Shortcodes',
        icon: false,
        onselect: function(e) {
        },
        values: [
    {
    text: 'Vídeos',
        onclick: function() {       
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Vídeo Incorporado',
                body: [
                    {type: 'listbox',
                    name: 'video_site',
                    label: 'Escolha o site de origem',
                    'values': [
                        {text: 'YouTube', value: 'youtube'},
                        {text: 'Vimeo', value: 'vimeo'},
                        {text: 'Vine', value: 'vine'}
                    ]},

                    {type: 'textbox',
                    name: 'video_id',
                    label: 'ID do vídeo',
                    value: '' },

                    {type: 'checkbox',
                    name: 'video_autoplay',
                    label: 'Executar automaticamente?',
                    text: 'Sim',
                    classes: 'checkclass' },
                ],

onsubmit: function( e ) {
editor.insertContent('[video origem="' + e.data.video_site + '" id="' + e.data.video_id + '" autoplay='+ e.data.video_autoplay +']'); }
                           });
                       } 
                   } 
               ]
          });
   });
})();
```

O *shortcode* gerado será algo como `[video id="XXXX" origem="YouTube" autoplay="true"]`.

A janela fica assim:

[image: popup tinymce gerado]

Esse é o HTML da *checkbox*:

```
<div id="mceu_130" class="mce-checkclass mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" unselectable="on" aria-labelledby="mceu_130-l" tabindex="-1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" style="left: 213px; top: 0px; width: 187px; height: 19px;">
   <i class="mce-ico mce-i-checkbox"></i>
   <span id="mceu_130-al" class="mce-label">Sim</span>
</div>
```

HTML da *listbox* aberta:

```
<div id="mceu_139" class="mce-container mce-panel mce-floatpanel mce-menu mce-fixed mce-menu-align" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="application" style="border-width: 1px; z-index: 100102; left: 735.5px; top: 136.145835876465px; width: 185px;">
  <div id="mceu_139-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout" role="menu" style="width: 185px;">
    <div id="mceu_140" class="mce-menu-item mce-menu-item-normal mce-first mce-stack-layout-item" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-checked="false" aria-pressed="false"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-none"></i>&nbsp;<span id="mceu_140-text" class="mce-text">YouTube</span></div>
    <div id="mceu_141" class="mce-menu-item mce-menu-item-normal mce-stack-layout-item" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-checked="false" aria-pressed="false"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-none"></i>&nbsp;<span id="mceu_141-text" class="mce-text">Vimeo</span></div>
    <div id="mceu_153" class="mce-menu-item mce-menu-item-normal mce-last mce-stack-layout-item" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-checked="false" aria-pressed="false"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-none"></i>&nbsp;<span id="mceu_153-text" class="mce-text">Vine</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

E esse é o HTML da *listbox* com a opção Vine selecionada:

```
<div id="mceu_131" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-menubtn mce-listbox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_131-l" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" style="left: 213px; top: 0px; width: 184.33333325386px; height: 28.3333332538605px;" aria-expanded="false">
   <button id="mceu_131-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
   <span>Vine</span> <i class="mce-caret"></i>
   </button> 
</div>
```

O problema é que nem todos os sites de vídeo dão a opçao *autoplay*, então eu preciso que, ao mudar o *listbox* para esses sites, o *checkbox* desapareça/seja desativado. O máximo que consegui foi criar um *alert* avisando que aquele site não aceita o parâmetro *autoplay*, removendo o atributo no *shortcode* final, mas é bem gambiarra.

Como fazer para, ao mudar a *listbox* para "Vine", por exemplo, desativar o *checkbox*? E trazê-lo de volta se o *listbox* voltar para outro como YouTube?

Comment: Você pode incluir o HTML que esse código gera? Inspecione o DOM com as ferramentas do browser e veja como está o HTML do checkbox. E você pode tentar `document.querySelector('[name="video_autoplay"]').disabled = true;`

Comment: O HTML do checkbox:

`<div id="mceu_137" class="mce-checai mce-last mce-abs-layout-item mce-checked" unselectable="on" aria-labelledby="mceu_137-l" tabindex="-1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" style="left: 213px; top: 0px; width: 187px; height: 19px;"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-checkbox"></i><span id="mceu_137-al" class="mce-label"></span></div>`

Inclui uma classe nele, mas ainda não consegui apontar pra ele ao mudar o listbox...

Comment: O problema é interceptar a mudança do listbox, desabilitar o checkbox, ou ambos? Se envolver a mudança do listbox, precisamos ver o html dele também.

Comment: É desabilitar o checkbox assim que o listbox tiver o value "vine", e reabilitar quando tiver o value "youtube". Isso antes de confirmar o shortcode, ou seja, interceptar a mudança, e de acordo com value, desabilitar ou não o checkbox. Vou postar o código completo do tinymce e o HTML gerado.

Comment: @DanielLemes podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar o HTML desse select onde escolhes `Vine`? Aí vamos poder responder como fazer isso.

Comment: Feito. Até consigo pegar a mudança da caixa com uma função (onselect) na _listbox_:
`if (this.value() == 'vine')`
e...
`$('input[type="checkbox"][name="video_autoplay"]').prop('disabled',true);`
...mas não funciona e o menu não recolhe ao selecionar o Vine.

Comment: Pelo visto esse checkbox gerado pelo TinyMCE não é um checkbox de verdade, deve ser por isso que não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui ajuda no WordPress.StackExchange. Uma solução para "acertar" o alvo (o checkbox e seu label) é criar uma *var* com a janela e então trazê-la com a função *onselect* do menu.

Ficou assim o script finalizado e funcionando. Note que adicionei *setStyle* para reduzir a opacidade dos elementos desabilitados (acabei criando dois, não soube como usar um array ali, se é possível...).

```
{
    text: 'Vídeos',
    onclick: function() {   
        var win = editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Vídeo Incorporado',
            body: [
                {type: 'checkbox',
                name: 'video_autoplay',
                label: 'Executar automaticamente?',
                text: 'Sim',
                id: 'check-autoplay',
                },

                {type: 'listbox',   
                name: 'video_site',
                onselect: function( ) {
                    var autoplay = win.find('#video_autoplay');
                    if (this.value() == 'vine') {
                        autoplay.disabled(true);
                        autoplay.value('');
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay-l','opacity', '.5');
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay','opacity', '.5');
                    } 
                    else {
                        autoplay.disabled(false);
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay','opacity', '1');     
                        tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle( 'check-autoplay-l','opacity', '1');
                    }   
                },
                label: 'Escolha o site de origem',
                    'values': [
                        {text: 'YouTube', value: 'youtube'},
                        {text: 'Vimeo', value: 'vimeo'},
                        {text: 'Vine', value: 'vine'},
                    ],
                },

                {type: 'textbox',
                name: 'video_id',
                label: 'Video ID',
                value: ''
                },
            ],

        onsubmit: function( e ) {
            editor.insertContent('[video origem="' + e.data.video_site + '" id="' + e.data.video_id +'" autoplay="'+ e.data.video_autoplay +'"]');
        }
    });
}
},
```